# How to display data from Firestore in Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I want to display the fullName of the user. It is stored in Firestore as you can see below.  I am trying but nothing is working. How can I fix this?

[image] [image]

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:file_picker/file_picker.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:camera/camera.dart';
import 'package:flutter_dev/reusable.dart';

class Fy extends StatefulWidget {
  const Fy({super.key});

  @override
  State<Fy> createState() => _FyState();
}

class _FyState extends State<Fy> {
  PlatformFile? pickedFile;

  dynamic data;

  dynamic user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
  final db = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

  Future getName() async {
    final getFullName = db.collection("users").doc(user.uid);

    getFullName.get().then((DocumentSnapshot doc) {
      setState(() {
        dynamic data = doc.data["fullName"].toString();
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center, children: [
          Text(
            'Hello $data}}',
            style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
          ),
          Text(
            '${user.uid}',
            style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
          ),
        ]),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The error line
[image]

Comment: Did you already set breakpoints on all lines of the code you shared, run in the debugger, and check the values of each variable on each line? If so, what is the **first** line that doesn't do what you expect it to do? That'd also be a great way to get rid of the long string of `aaaaaaa`, and replace it with information that will actually help us help you.

Comment: I have to learn first how to debug, it will help me for sure ! The bad line is -- dynamic data = doc.data["fullName"].toString(); --

Comment: With error : The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Object? Function()'.
Try defining the operator '[]'.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen

Comment: This error has come up quite a few times before: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgoogle-cloud-firestore%5D%5Bflutter%5D+The+operator+%27%5B%5D%27+isn%27t+defined+for+the+type+%27Object%3F+Function%28%29%27.+Try+defining+the+operator+%27%5B%5D%27 You might also want to check the reference docs for [doc.data](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/DocumentSnapshot/data.html), because as far as I can see that is a method.

Comment: Try this: `String data = (doc.data as Map<String, dynamic>)["fullName"].toString();`

Comment: Thanks but I find an other way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I find it myself if it can help someone**

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:file_picker/file_picker.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:camera/camera.dart';
import 'package:flutter_dev/reusable.dart';

class Fy extends StatefulWidget {
  const Fy({super.key});

  @override
  State<Fy> createState() => _FyState();
}

class _FyState extends State<Fy> {
  PlatformFile? pickedFile;


  final db = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
  final user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Center(
      child: StreamBuilder(
          stream: db.collection("users").doc(user!.uid).snapshots(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (!snapshot.hasData) return const Text('Loading Data..');
            return Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Text('Hello ' +
                  snapshot.data!['fullName'],
                  style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 10,
                ),
                Text('Your email : ' +
                  snapshot.data!['email'],
                  style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20),
                ),
              ],
            );
          }),
    ));
  }
}
```